# wired ruby hash each function

Tags: ruby, hash, enumeration

Well I've tried this for many times and tried to figure out what'd happened...

Suppose I wish to sum the amount of a bunch of objects in hash:

```
orders = [{:price => 100, :qty => 5}, {:price => 120, :qty => 10}, {:price => 50, :qty => 5}]
```

I want to sum every hash object in the array items as above....

Assuming variable "sum" is the result:

```
sum = 0
sum = orders.each {|i| sum += i[:price] * i[:qty]}
```

but it returns the same hash object:

```
[{:price => 100, :qty => 5}, {:price => 120, :qty => 10}, {:price => 50, :qty => 5}]
```

I thought the result should be 0 + (100 * 5) + (120 * 10) + (50 * 5)

why is it so?

my solution for this is by doing the following:
    sum = 0
    total = []
    orders.each {|i| total << i[:price] * i[:qty]}
    total.each {|i| sum += i}

I think it is not intuitive at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Hash#each returns itself, if block is given. See docs here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-each

The right way to do what you want is

```
sum = orders.map {|o| o[:price] * o[:qty] }.inject(0, :+)
```

Comment: Why do map/inject, when one can do just inject?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Enumerable#each` returns a collection it enumerated. You typically don't use its return value at all. You already are modifying sum in the block, so you're good.

```
sum = 0    
orders.each {|i| sum += i[:price] * i[:qty]}
```

A better way would be to use a specialized method for this

```
orders = [{:price => 100, :qty => 5}, {:price => 120, :qty => 10}, {:price => 50, :qty => 5}]

sum = orders.reduce(0) do |memo, item|
  memo + item[:price] * item[:qty]
end

sum # => 1950
```